# check if given domain name present in set of urls php

Tags: php, url, dns

I have an url whose format may be : 

  www.discover.com
  http://discover.com
  http://www.discover.com
  http://www.abcd.discover.com
  discover.com

And i have another url which may be any of below format: 

  www.discover.com/something/smoething
  http://discover.com/something/smoething
  http://www.discover.com/something/smoething
  http://www.abcd.discover.com/something/smoething
  discover.com/something/smoething

Now i want to compare this two urls to check whether domain name "discover.com" is present in the second url.

Am using below code :

```
$domain1 = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($urlItem1, PHP_URL_HOST));
    $domain2= str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($urlItem2, PHP_URL_HOST));

    if(strstr($domain2, $domain1))
    {
        return $domain2;
    }
```

Solution :

```
function url_comparison($url1, $url2) {
$domain1 = parse_url($url1,PHP_URL_HOST);
$domain2 = parse_url($url2,PHP_URL_HOST);

$domain1 = isset($domain1) ? str_ireplace('www.', '',$domain1) : str_ireplace('www.', '',$url1); 
$domain2 = isset($domain2) ? str_ireplace('www.', '',$domain2) : str_ireplace('www.', '',$url2);

if(strstr($domain2, $domain1))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

$url1 = "discover.com";
$url2 = "https://www.abcd.discover.com/credit-cards/resources/balance-transfer.shtml";

if(url_comparison($url1, $url2))
{
echo "Same Domain";
}
else
{
echo "Diffrent Domain";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your tried code?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the documentation, [parse url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Then you should look at the hostname, and with use of strpos.

```
$url = parse_url('www.discover.com/something/smoething');

if (strpos($url['host'], 'discover.com') !== false) {
  // do you thing
}
```

*0 is also a valid value so the !== or === is needed*

To check if two domain are equal you need to set some rules, because is www.example.com the same as example.com, and is https the same as http?

```
function url_comparison($url_1, $url_2, $www = false, $scheme = false) {
    $url_part_1 = parse_url($url_1);
    $url_part_2 = parse_url($url_2);

    if ($scheme && $url_part_1['scheme'] !== $url_part_2['scheme']) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($www && $url_part_1['host'] === $url_part_2['host']) {
        return false;
    } elseif(!$www && (strpos($url_part_1['host'], $url_part_2['host']) !== false || strpos($url_part_2['host'], $url_part_1['host']) !== false)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

With the above function you should see the right direction, not tested so should be tweaked perhaps. The first 2 values should be an url. `$www` is a boolean if the 'www.' should be checked, and if `$scheme = true` also the https or http needs to be the same

Comment: 1) You've referenced a function but not even used it in your answer. 2) If you had used it you would know that `hostname` is not returned by that function.

Comment: Was to quick at the docs, and saw hostname, but is host. So thanks for pointing it out and edited the answer with the data you gave

Comment: discover.com is just an example, i would like to check if domain name of url1 is same as domain name of url2 then return true else return false

Comment: parse_url of "discover.com" doesnt give host, so it return an error

Comment: Did not see that one, but you are right, you need to add a scheme (http(s)) so it works, so http://discover.com works

Comment: cant say user can enter urls with scheme or not ... need a fucntion which can take any type of urls and compare domain name ...

Comment: Check if the url has a scheme and if it has no you add it. And a valid url is with a scheme

Comment: have edited my question with a solution ... can u pls check and tell does that fails in any condition checking the domain of two urls??

Comment: Well there are lot of combination, and I don't know them all, but it looks like it works. Just write some couple test cases and find it out.

Comment: have tested my self ... but wana make sure it works for all conditions ... anyway thanks ....